# Urls indexed in Google with index.php, Laravel configured to not use it in paths

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I deployed recently an little website made with latest Laravel 4.
All works well, url rewriting included.

But I noticed that Google indexed a few urls with the `index.php` in the path. As you know, this can provoke a duplicate content problem.

I triple checked, and there's absolutely no way to access an url with `index.php` when you browse the website. So I wonder how to prevent the framework to load the urls with `index.php`, or at least a trick to redirect automatically to the correct url without the `index.php`.

In the original htaccess, I only added this to force the www in url:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

I don't think it's the cause of this problem, but I mention it, just in case.

Thanks.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same problem, want to prevent the index.php url from ever showing up.

Comment: If I remember well, the request to remove those urls (in Google Webmaster Tools) had an effect a few days later. I also see I use now this in my htaccess (I'm on Laravel 4.1 now):
        `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me, helping me removine Laravel's `index.php` from the url:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: `R=301` is also good, it let's google know the site has been moved and it won't bother about the original url anymore. But with `R=301` the redirect is visible, without its invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Google saves 404 pages, use Google Webmastertools to remove from their cache.

The Rule is wrong I think.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1
```

Comment: Yes, that's right I already removed these urls from GWT. You suggest I replace the original `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`? Tried, but no change. I'm not sure it's a mod rewrite issue, but a Laravel issue, that's why I did not put the related tag. And urls are not 404, they actually work. They are just not supposed to be indexed (because not in source code).

Comment: Search engines keep even URL's you had months ago in cache. There may be hidden comments in sourcecode to the original /index.php path. Or in sitemap.xml, or in news feeds...

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, but as I said, answer is no :) I made 0 urls with index.php, neither in html comments, sitemap is clean, and that's it (it's a quite simple app). I put back laravel tag front, as it's a Laravel issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `url` config option at `/app/config/app.php`  It will be `localhost` by default. And make sure that your .htaccess file is in the public folder and your server (eg. apache) is pointing to the public folder of your app. Make a `composer dump-autoload --optimize` and a `php artisan optimize`

Comment: As far as I remember, this setting was okay (I use an app.php for local and another one for prod server). Thanks for the suggestion anyway (the problem solved by itself a few days later).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this .htaccess syntax:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```